# Error when tried to install 3 operation systems

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems, gparted, fdisk

I would like to have 3 Operation Systems on my Hard disk drive ,namely 2 Linux (e.g. Ubuntu and Debian) and 1 windows(e.g. Windows 7).

How should I partition my HDD? (Which file systems and What settings(like root))

Edit1 : When I tried to install 3rd OS on 3rd partition (which is ex4), I receive this error:

```
No root file system is defined
```

Screenshot of my HDD structure:

sda1 -> Linux

sda2 -> Windows

[image]

Comment: At least 1 partition for each system. If you have 8+GB RAM, forget the swap partition. Linux partitions with ext4 file system. Windows with NTFS obviously. Install Windows. Install Debian. Install ubuntu. Easy.

Comment: so your suggestion is ex4, NTFS, ex4 ?

Comment: Are you asking about order of file systems? you have 200 GB HDD. Create 1st partition 80 GB,  format as NTFS. Create 2nd partition 60 GB, format as ext4. Create 3rd part, format as ext4.

Comment: The only requirement is for windows to be installed on ntfs partition. Also, windows should be installed first, and it will create an additional system partition with around 1GB for system files/booting purposes.

Comment: I already installed windows as NTFS but 2nd. will it be a problem for installing 3rd OS ?

Comment: I update the question with screenshot

Comment: I need to solve this problem. Any suggestion?